# SQL query gives strange and false STDEV(STEDP)

Tags: python, sql

I try to get the the std and mean for a large set of values(A), sub grouped by another column (B). The mean value is correct and some STD values seem correct but others are completely wrong. Please note that the ABS is needed due to the measurement system calculating reverse movement as negative movment.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as db

query='SELECT AVG(ABS(A)) as Mean, STDEV(ABS(A)) as Std FROM db GROUP BY B'
engine = db.create_engine('MyUrl')
connection = engine.connect()
df_Stat= pd.read_sql(sql=query,con=connection)
connection.close()
```

Example of resault Std for B1 = 5.7 which is way to high. 
The average is calculated correctly 5.9 from the query and 5.9 from numpy.

If i calculate the std my self with numpy i get

```
In[101]: np.std(A['B' = 'B1'])
Out[101]: 0.3511883254512004
In[102]: np.mean(A['B' = 'B1'])
Out[102]: 5.940183137474761
```

I cant seem to understand why this would happen. 
Here is some of the data that result in the false std value.

```
index     B1
0   5.610462
1   5.401573
2   5.698431
3   5.458077
4   6.333272
5   5.630164
6   6.345271
7   5.817740
8   6.332081
9   5.853444
10  6.486144
11  5.677099
12  6.261545
13  5.800019
14  6.308420
15  5.856949
16  6.130642
17  5.730136
18  6.162707
19  5.785853
20  6.131579
21  5.651739
22  6.185134
23  5.681923
24  6.260339
25  5.780885
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be useful. And what database you're using.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, the data base is a Microsoft sql.
I have added some sample data in the original post.

Comment: Your SQL gets the average and stddev of column A grouped by column B but that table has neither of those?

Comment: I agree this was misleading, the data displayed is from column A from a subgroup defined by column B, ie.B1.

Think off A as rpm readings and B as different motors, the data displayed is all rpm readings for motor B1.
The mean rpm for B1 is such ~= 5.94 & std ~= 0.35.
But the sql query gives me the std to be 5.7.